How can my Flask application push Websocket Messages to an asynchronous HTML page?
I'm having a few issues with a Flask application using socketIO.
I have an external device on IP 10.0.0.144 sending websocket messages to my application on 10.0.0.218:8089. I can see the incoming websocket messages in the PyCharm console.
10.0.0.144 - - [31/Jul/2024 11:21:43] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('{"ts":1722439304,"dio":{"dio1":{"in":true},"dio2":{"in":true},"dio3":{"label":"Link","in":true},"dio4":{"in":true}},"ain":{"ain1":{"voltage":12},"ain2":{"voltage":2},"ain3":{"voltage":10},"ain4":{"voltage":0}}}') 

10.0.0.144 - - [31/Jul/2024 11:21:43] "{"ts":1722439304,"dio":{"dio1":{"in":true},"dio2":{"in":true},"dio3":{"label":"Link","in":true},"dio4":{"in":true}},"ain":{"ain1":{"voltage":12},"ain2":{"voltage":2},"ain3":{"voltage":10},"ain4":{"voltage":0}}}" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST

Additionally I'm trying to push these messages to an asynchronous HTML page, but the messages aren't being pushed across from what I can see.
Flask code:
I wanted this to process the incoming messages and then push them to an asynchronous HTML page. The messages are being processed, and I have them stored in a list object. I'm really only concerned with messages originating from 10.0.0.144.
I'm honestly not even sure if this is the best approach from a project standpoint, but I've never done anything this advanced before.

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import *
from threading import Thread, Event
import socket
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Shared variable to store messages
messages = []

thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    # need visibility of the global thread object
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    #Start the function to emit msgs thread only if the thread has not been started before.
    if not thread.is_alive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(start_socket_server)

def start_socket_server(host='10.0.0.218', port=8089):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        if message:
            # print(f"{addr, message}")
            messages.append(message)
            # Send the message to all connected clients
            socketio.emit('new_message', {'message': message})
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start the socket server in a separate thread
    socket_thread = Thread(target=start_socket_server)
    socket_thread.start()

    # Start the Flask app with SocketIO
    socketio.run(app, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)

JS code:
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect()
    var messages_received = [];

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('new_message', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received msg" + msg.number);
        //maintain a list of ten msgs
        if (messages_received.length >= 10){
            messages_received.shift()
        }
        messages_received.push(msg.number);
        messages_string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < messages_received.length; i++){
                messages_string += '<p>' + messages_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
        }
        $('#log').html(messages_string);
    });

});

Here's a sample of the output console:
\`\* Running on http://10.0.0.218:8089
Press CTRL+C to quit

* Restarting with stat
  Server initialized for threading.
  Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.

* Debugger is active!

* Debugger PIN: 123-630-169
  RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA', 'upgrades': \['websocket'\], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:54:54\] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P49W5nO HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/test,
  RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0/test,{"sid":"Fzb-QYWF3SFFBr4EAAAB"}
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:54:54\] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P49W64r&sid=RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:54:54\] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P49W64s&sid=RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
  Client connected
  Starting Thread
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  10.0.0.144 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:54:59\] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('{"ts":1722441301,"dio":{"dio1":{"in":true},"dio2":{"in":true},"dio3":{"label":"Link","in":true},"dio4":{"in":true}},"ain":{"ain1":{"voltage":12},"ain2":{"voltage":2},"ain3":{"voltage":10},"ain4":{"voltage":0}}}')
  10.0.0.144 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:54:59\] "{"ts":1722441301,"dio":{"dio1":{"in":true},"dio2":{"in":true},"dio3":{"label":"Link","in":true},"dio4":{"in":true}},"ain":{"ain1":{"voltage":12},"ain2":{"voltage":2},"ain3":{"voltage":10},"ain4":{"voltage":0}}}" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  emitting event "new_message" to all \[/\]
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:55:05\] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=RMoYImBp0_FvWs_lAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:55:05\] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  Client disconnected
  10.0.0.218 - - \[31/Jul/2024 11:55:05\] "GET /static/application.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -\`

HTML page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/application.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Asynchronous Flask Communication</h2>
    <p>Websocket Messages from field devices.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Asynchronous page updates will appear here:</p>
        <h3>messages:</h3>
        <div id="log">
        </div> <!-- /#log -->
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>


Did you check with Chrome devtools? To check If js could correclty Connect to websocket on the Webpage ? Also this looks Strange: var socket = io.connect('http://10.0.0.218' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test') why you add domain to an ip address?

Hi, I changed var socket = io.connect() and I can see what is going on in devtools now.
This is the error I'm receiving in devtools:
Received msg[object Object]
application.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
so looks like the value being passed into the JS app can't be processed for one reason or another.

This is the issue messages_received[i].toString(), do console.log for the message_recived etc. to see why messages_received[i] is null/undefinied

I figured it out:
//receive details from server

        console.log("Received msg" + msg.number);         messages_received.push(msg.number);
The msg.number variable should be msg.messages

Leason: Always check devtools when working with js frontend and use console.log for Debugging hehe
